# Is the number of different patterns possible permutations or combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I was given the below question.

"Linus is taking a true or false test and seems to be guessing every answer. If there are $20$ questions how many different "patterns" are possible?"

I solved this questions by seeing that there are $2$ choices at each of the $20$ questions, so I wrote $2^{20}$ patterns.

However, I am still unsure of whether this is $2^{20}$ combinations or permutations. I am finding it difficult to see whether the order matters in questions like this.

Support would be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: It is neither combinations nor permutations.  Your $2^{20}$ is spot on.  This is just a "multiplication" rule, number of choices for step 1 (2), number of choices for setp 2 (2), ... number of choices for step $k$ (2).  A total of $2\cdot 2\cdot ... \cdot 2=2^{k}$ sequences.

Comment: What do you mean by a pattern? Any configuration of answers or answers that repeat themselves every x number of questions? The latter is going to just be "number of options" raised to the "number of questions" power, while the latter is harder to determine.

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused now because the answer below says that there are 20 permutations.

Comment: @AlfredYerger By "pattern" I mean the number of ways the questions can be answered.

Comment: Permutations count the number of ways to put $n$ different things in some order, there are $n!$ ways to do this.  Do you have 20 different things that you are placing in some order?  No.  What you have is the same as counting the number of strings of length 20 built from a 2 character alphabet, $\{T, F\}$.  I'm trying to politely warn you that the answer posted below is not correct (in their use of permutation/combination).  We agree though that your count is correct.

Comment: @TravisJ So does that mean that whenever I use the multiplicative rule I am not finding the number of combinations or permutations?

Comment: You can use the multiplication rule to find the number of permutations, for example, step 1: choose 1 of the $n$ items ($n$-choices), step 2: choose 1 of the remaining $n-1$ items ($n-1$-choices), ... , step $n$ choose the last remaining item ($1$-choice).  This give a total of $n(n-1)...(1)=n!$ choices.  You could get there by counting perms, or using the multiplication principle.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. Thank you :)

Comment: The thing you need to keep in mind is what does "permutations" count, and what does "combinations" count.  The first is the number of ways to place $n$ distinct things in some order--so the order is important.  The latter, $C(n,k)$ or $\binom{n}{k}$, counts the number of ways to select $k$ distinct things from $n$ distinct things where you only care which $k$ are selected, not which order they are selected in.

Comment: Yes I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the number of different patterns possible permutations or
>   combinations?

As you've observed, $2^{20}$ is the number of binary sequences of length $20$; i.e., two possibilities for each sequence-position gives $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot 2 = 2^{20}$ sequences.

It's worth mentioning, as well, that $2^{20}$ is the *total number of **combinations*** of the $20$ sequence-positions when any number of them ($0, 1, 2, ..., 20$) may be taken at a time -- which, of course, is the same as the total number of subsets of the size-$20$ set of positions.

(By definition, a "combination of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time" is any size-$k$ subset of a size-$n$ set, and the number of combinations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time is denoted $\binom{n}{k}$.)

The above result follows from the fact that the number of length-$20$ binary sequences *with a specific composition* (say, exactly $k$ $T$s and $20-k$ $F$s) is equal to the number of size-$k$ subsets of the size-$20$ set of sequence-positions, since the sequence is completely determined by placing a $T$ at each position in the subset and filling the other positions with $F$s.

Thus, the *total* number of length-$20$ binary sequences is the sum over all the different compositions -- all those with exactly $0$ $T$s, plus all those with exactly $1$ $T$, plus all those with exactly $2$ $T$s, ..., plus all those with exactly $20$ $T$s:

$$2^{20} = \binom{20}{0} + \binom{20}{1} + \binom{20}{2} + \ ... \ + \binom{20}{20}
$$

More generally, for any nonnegative integer $n$, 
$$2^n = \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} +\ ...\ + \binom{n}{n}.
$$